# Why different behavior in calling a function with providing arguments in distinct ways in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, interface

While learning [interfaces in TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html) i found strange thing which I am unable to understand

**Case 1:** (no error)

```
function  p_label(argument: {lab: string}) {
    console.log(argument.lab);
}

let obj = {dabloo: 'dablooo', lab: 'chem'};
p_label(obj);
```

op: chem

here object is assigned (using `let`) to a variable  and then passed to a argument in a funtion

**Case 2:** (error)

```
function  p_label(argument: {lab: string}) {
    console.log(argument.lab);
}

p_label({dabloo: 'dablooo', lab: 'chem'});
```

> interfaces.ts(8,14): error TS2345: Argument of type '{ dabloo: string;
>   lab: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ lab: string;
>   }'.   Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'dabloo'
>   does not exist in type '{ lab: string; }'.

Here whole object is passed directly to a argument without assingning it to a variable.

What I see here by seeing the error is that argument is considered as a prototype of the object but not the object itself.

I think very few or no other programming language consider it seperately.

Why this kind of behavior? Or whats wrong with my unserstanding?

tsc --version

2.5.2

Comment: Read the TypeScript Handbook section on [Excess Property Checking](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#excess-property-checks).

Comment: Thanks jcalz, link you provided is the answer.